# Google Play doesn't accept app bundle with any Huawei dependency

Tags: android, google-play, huawei-mobile-services

When I want to upload app bundle to GooglePlay with any Huawei dependency it gives error without any information.

[image]

I tried all of these one by one and every time it gave error until I remove all of these from gradle. I tried to add these dependencies to another app and publish however result was same.

[image]

However interestingly I can upload APK without any error.

Comment: well yes, that's why huawei has its own store, isn't it ?

Comment: The title is misleading because it is not in Google's public interest to block 3rd party libraries - at this case - Huawei's libraries. More likely this is related to a dependency conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem should be caused by Language package problem.

You can go to the application's build.gradle file, in android->defaultConfig, limit the languege resources to what you'd like to use:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        resConfigs "en", "fr"  //pick the languages you'd like to use
    }
}
```

Then rebuild the .aab file and try uploading.

Comment: This worked but I don't understand what can cause this problem, do you know any detail about this , I am asking for my curiosity?

Comment: I thought about it as well, the problem should be invloved becase of some language packages, but why these packages influence the upload, no ideas for now.

Answer (score 1):

APK can you uploaded, but Google play console showing error (red icon) while uploading app bundle. since google console is not showing any tip or error details. If you are using Huawei services HMS core related libraries in your application you need to use the latest
Huawei push services and it will resolve the problem with app bundle upload.

```
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:push:5.0.4.302'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to upload APK instead of AppBundle. We faced same issue two weeks ago and fix it with uploading APK.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Push Kit **5.0.2.300** has not fixed the issue yet. The latest version of SDK will be released in November 16 [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/version-change-history-0000001050040072-V5?ha_source=hms1). Please update it to **5.0.4.302**.

---

This problem is a known bug and it has been rectified already. Please update the HMS Core SDK to latest version [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/hmssdk-kit-0000001050042513-V5?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: I removed all and tried with just "com.huawei.hms:push". My version was "5.0.0.300". I updated to latest "5.0.2.300" but result is same. Is there anything that I can try?

Comment: I found that Push Kit 5.0.2.300 does not fix the problem. The new version will be released today (Noverber 16)! @Cembora

Comment: push 5.0.3.302 would not work, Please implementation 'com.huawei.hms:push:5.0.4.302'